# Problema al mostrar bases de datos

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Quería localizar la ruta donde se encuentran alojadas mis bases de datos, con el objetivo de configurar un archivo .bat para hacer copias de seguridad automáticas.

En el servidor donde tengo instalado el PHPMYADMIN hago lo siguiente, monstrandome las siguientes bases de datos, y no me aparecen las mias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo, si accedo a través de phpmyadmin estas son las bases de datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que estoy haciendo mal? Como puedo mostrar mis bases de datos mediante la ventana de comandos de windows?

Answer (score 2):

Parece que el usuario "root" no tiene permisos para esas tablas.

Puedes conectarte a mysql con el usuario que utilizas para phpmyadmin, y después lanzar los siguientes comandos;

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%';
```

Y después el comando;

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Answer (score 0):

En phpmyadmin el usuario root ya tiene privilegios en las bases de datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Las bases de datos "sakila" y "world" no existen cuando entro en el navegador en el phpmyadmin, parece como si el directorio al que accedo mediante la ventana de comandos fuese distinto al directorio de base de datos al que accedo mediante el navegador con phpmyadmin.

No se, estoy algo perdido, alguien tiene alguna idea de lo que puede estar pasando?

Si voy al directorio: C:\xampp\mysql\data si que me encuentro con las bases de datos que veo con phpmyadmin, pero accediendo por ventana de comandos no las veo.